# Unable to channel docker-registry stdout to log file

Tags: docker, stdout

I've been trying (rather futilely) this afternoon to try and stop docker-registry from writing to stdout but rather a log but I think the underlying Python is creating processes which seem to bypass all efforts of channelling to a log.

I've tried the usual `>` and `2>&1` and with piping to various commands but it all seems to escape my grasp.

Is there anyway I can get **all** output of this command to go straight to a log rather than stdout?

[edit]

This is the script I'm using to start it up, it's part of a shell script I plan to use as a service

```
start() {
  # Sugar
  echo -e "Starting registry"

  # Run the registry
  export LOGLEVEL=NOTSET
  export AWS_BUCKET=$TargetBucket
  export AWS_KEY=$AWSAccessKey
  export AWS_SECRET=$AWSSecretKey
  docker-registry & 2>&1 | tee $LogFile

  # Create a lock file
  touch $LockFile
}
```

Comment: What OS/distribution? How do you start the process? What settings do you have in your `docker-registry.yaml` WRT `logvel` and `*_logfile`?

Comment: I don't appear to have a docker-registry.yaml or yml file anywhere, I'm running CentOS 6.5 and docker 1.0. For what it's worth I installed docker-registry through pip rather than from the github repo.

Comment: According to [the github page of the project](https://github.com/dotcloud/docker-registry), you should have a `config_sample.yml` file. Otherwise, you would need to write one and place it in the `config` dir, I don't know where does the `pip` install places it.

Comment: I'm doing everything with environmentals, seems easier that way although no differing type of logging level appears to make a difference.

Comment: I've added the part of the shell script I'm using to start it to the original post to see if it's just something I've missed through frustration.

Comment: Why are you using `tee`?

Comment: It's just the last thing I tried to use to write to the log instead of stdout.

Answer (score 2):

In case other still looking for the answer, I just realize with myself recently.

When you install the docker-registry rpm and start the service, the log file is store within systemd journal file itself.

Here is the command to retrieve the log:
sudo journalctl -fu docker-registry.service

The same way to get docker log also.

You can also edit the /usr/lib/systemd/system/docker-registry.service and replace the - after  --access-logfile with the file you want.  Service restart is required.

Answer (score 0):

Make your life easier by using the precompiled packages available in EPEL: [docker-io-1.0.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/docker-io-1.0.0-6.el6.x86_64.rpm) and [docker-registry-0.7.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm](https://dl.fedoraproject.org/pub/epel/6/x86_64/docker-registry-0.7.1-2.el6.noarch.rpm) as of this writing.

You will have and already working service script (no need to roll your own), you will receive updates (easier than recompiling or reinstalling from `pip`) and OS integration.

Your problem with logs disappears, as logs are configured in the `/etc/docker-registry.yaml` file (referenced from `/etc/sysconfig/docker-registry` using `DOCKER_REGISTRY_CONFIG=/etc/docker-registry.yml`)

You can define where you logs point to using the `loglevel:` directive in the `common` section, or per-provider using `*_logfile:`.

If you prefer to stick with a manual installation, note that usually the `docker-registry` is serverd by `gunicorn`, using the following command (this is taken from a Fedora 20 installation, it shouldn't be too different):

```
/usr/bin/gunicorn --access-logfile - --debug --max-requests 100 --graceful-timeout 3600 \
  -t 3600 -k gevent -b ${REGISTRY_ADDRESS}:${REGISTRY_PORT} -w $GUNICORN_WORKERS \
  docker_registry.wsgi:application
```

(The `--access-logfile` being the `stdin` is a `systemd` thing)

Comment: That docker registry rpm doesn't actually appear to do anything? Says service has started but `nmap`, `netstat`, `pidof` and `ps aux` all show nothing..